# Firebird random integer syntax

Tags: random, firebird, procedure

```
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE PROCEDURE ljudjee
AS 
DECLARE VARIABLE i integer=1;
DECLARE VARIABLE d integer; 
DECLARE VARIABLE e integer;
DECLARE VARIABLE star integer;   
BEGIN
while (i <= 1000000) do
begin
  d=((rand()*99999)+1);
  e=((rand()*99999)+1);
  star=((rand()*50)+18);
  insert into ljudje values (:i,'Ime','Priimek',:star,:d,:e);
  i = i + 1;
  END
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

Well i dont get any errors from this code when executing it. It seems like everything is ok but when i try to EXECUTE PROCEDURE it doesnt work. There are also no errors but procedure execution time takes forever and actually does nothing. It must be something wrong with rand() function which i probably didnt use correctly. Any ideas? Also no records are inserted into the table. None at all.

Comment: You will see records in the table only if the procedure is completed correctly. Either there is error or procedure is terminated then no records would get into the table. Try to decrease iterations count to 10. Does procedure still hung?

Comment: Procedure works if i put count to 10. It does not when put count to 1000000. I leave it alone for like 30 minutes, but does nothing. It should be executed in a matter of seconds.

Comment: What happens if you execute this in a `NO WAIT` transaction?

Comment: Does ljudje table have some triggers?

Answer (score 0):

In case you havent found the issue.  You are inserting a million records in a single transaction.  You will not see some of them.  Its a all or nothing deal.  It could be that your database is not set up correctly in terms of caching and page sizes.  Often it is faster to drop any indexes, do the inserts and then create the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `trunc()`:

```
d = trunc((rand() * 99999) + 1);
e  = trunc((rand() * 99999) + 1);
star = trunc((rand() * 50) + 18);
```